# I am passing a string in if else if conditional statements ,but it is taking as a null and it is executing the else part in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which using if else ladder conditional statements,in else if statement a string is passed,but it is taking as null and it is executing the else part.Please suggest me why it is taking as null.Here is my code.

```
   if(HallTicket_Status.equals("HETSTOP")) 
   {
   android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(
   UpcomingEventsDetails.this).create();
   alertDialog.setTitle("Hall Ticket Generation Stopped!");
   alertDialog.setMessage("Hall Ticket generation for this event has been stopped. You can apply for other events, if you meet the eligibility criteria.");
   alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);
   alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void  onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
   });
   }
   else if (HallTicket_Status.equals("NE")) {
   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UpcomingEventsDetails.this, "NOT ELIGIBLE",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
   toast.show();
   } 
   else if (HallTicket_Status.equals("PNC")) {
   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UpcomingEventsDetails.this, "Please Check Your Profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
   toast.show();
   }
   else if(HallTicket_Status.equals("NPU")){
   Context context = getApplicationContext();
   CharSequence text = "This event is only for COSET subscribers,for more details please login into http://costuco.coset.com";
   int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
   toast.show();
   }
   else {
   Intent intent=new Intent(UpcomingEventsDetails.this,Hallticket.class);
   intent.putExtra("EVENT_ID",eventid);
   intent.putExtra("het_uid",b);
   Log.d("#$Request URL", eventid + "");
   Log.d("###$Response ", b + "");
   startActivity(intent);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

change **HallTicket_Status.equalsIgnoreCase("HETSTOP")** to **HallTicket_Status.equals("HETSTOP")**

Do it for all if case

Comment: Mind to tell us **why**?! https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm

Comment: I tried.But instead of "HETSTOP" it was taking as null value